# ui:include com rendered do JSF não funciona as ações

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

tenho dois `ui:include` dentro de um template, segue o exemplo abaixo:

```
/*Desse Jeito ele entra nos metodo corretamente!*/
<ui:include src="../home/dados.xhtml"></ui:include>

/* com rendered não entra no metodo */
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{param['lotes'] == true}">
    <ui:include src="../home/dados.xhtml"></ui:include>
</h:panelGroup>
```

porque ocorre isso? como posso resolver isso mt obrigado!

Comment: o problema deve ser o rendered a condição em vez de true deve dar false, se da false não renderiza o conteudo da tag e com isso nada é chamado mesmo

Answer (score -2):

Já passei por um problema neste sentido.

No meu caso foi apenas eu fazer da seguinte forma:

`<h:panelGroup rendered="#{param['lotes'] == 'true'}">
    <ui:include src="../home/dados.xhtml"> </ui:include>
/h:panelGroup>`